# Many text inputs with same name. Fire change for changed id only?

Tags: html, jquery

I have lots of text inputs and want to toggle the input field background green for 2 seconds to indicate success of a future ajax firing etc., but only for the field that changed. Not wrapping my head around this with jQuery.

So below... if I change the value of stats.1a to 5 only toggle stats.1a field to green and back... not all the others stats fields also. Etc.

Or am I just going about this the wrong way?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('[name="stats"]').on('change', function() {
    $('[name="stats"]'.id).css("background-color", "#adf0c2");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('[name="stats"]'.id).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="stats" id="1a" value="">
<input type="text" name="stats" id="2a" value="">
<input type="text" name="stats" id="3a" value="">
```

Comment: Always check that your selectors are working.   Change `$('[name="stats"]'.id).css...` to `console.log($('[name="stats"]'.id).length); $('[name="stats"]'.id).css...`  if it's 0 then the selector is wrong, so debug the selector string - `console.log('[name="stats"]'.id)`  - or use debugging tools - press F12 in the browser to get to the console to see the output

Comment: The year is 2055; why jQuery still? =P

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the element which raised the event by using `this` within the `change` handler.  It's the element itself, not a jQuery object, but any element can be wrapped in a jQuery object:

```
$(this)
```

From there, all you'd need to do is capture that reference in a variable so the `setTimeout` callback can close around that variable and still use the same reference 2 seconds later.

For example:

```js
$('[name="stats"]').on('change', function(){
  const $self = $(this);
  $self.css("background-color", "#adf0c2");
      setTimeout(function(){
          $self.css("background-color", "#ffffff");
      }, 2000);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="stats" id="1a" value="">
<input type="text" name="stats" id="2a" value="">
<input type="text" name="stats" id="3a" value="">
```

Comment: Thank you! I was... sorta... close anyways haha. I appreciate the hand hold!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("input").on("change", function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#adf0c2");
    setTimeout(() => {
      $(this).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

The main problem in your code is the following line:

```js
$('[name="stats"]'.id).css("background-color", "#adf0c2");
```

To add CSS properties to an element, write `$(element).css("key", "value")` instead.

---

By the way, the `name` attribute is used for HTTP requests (POST, GET) to the server, it may be more appropriate to use classes. If you need to identify the inputs, write `stats[]`, otherwise each one will be overwritten by the next input with the same value until the last one is reached.

So something like this would make more sense:

```html
<input type="text" name="stats[]" class="stats">
<input type="text" name="stats[]" class="stats">
<input type="text" name="stats[]" class="stats">
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, the main goal is to fire an ajax sql query when changing the value of the input box, which is why I was using name attribute for the POST instead of a class. I need to learn this stuff better for sure. I appreciate your response!